# Performance issues when calling MySQL stored procedure using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, stored-procedures

I'm trying to understand why the execution time of my stored procedure is so much higher when I run it from Java using Hibernate than when I run it directly in MySQL.

The stored procedure itself is responsible for moving 20000 rows from table A to table B and then delete them in table A.

Running the stored procedure in MySQL takes around 18 seconds.

In Java, I'm using Hibernate and create a query:

```
Query query =
    mainSession
        .createSQLQuery("{CALL my_stored_procedure(:maxResultSize)}")
        .setParameter("maxResultSize", maxResultSize);
```

Then the query is executed and the session is flushed and cleared:

```
List<BigInteger> rows = query.list();
mainSession.flush();
mainSession.clear();
```

This takes around 248 seconds.

Does anyone know why it takes so much more time to call the stored procedure from Java using Hibernate?

What approach should I take to increase the performance?

Comment: When testing directly in MySQL, did you fetch all rows?

Comment: Well I ran the same stored procedure

Comment: That does not necessarily mean that your client fetched all rows, which can sometimes lead to different performance characteristics.

Comment: Can I somehow test that?

Comment: Check the options in your query tool, they usually have an option (either in config, menu or query screen itself) to fetch a few pages or fetch all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Please could you try with native query, it is faster for me and work well.

```
List<Object[]> query = (List<Object[]>) mySessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createNativeQuery("{CALL my_stored_procedure(:maxResultSize)}")
        .setParameter("maxResultSize", maxResultSize).getResultList();
```

Comment: Hmm Session.createSQLQuery is Hibernate's way of creating a native query. Session.createNativeQuery does not exist. createNativeQuery is the JPA way of creating native queries. Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: @RichardSilvertass , I think hibernate 5.0 and above does not support for createSQLQuery.It is showed deprecetation . And we used with nativequery in hibernate 5.0

Comment: And createNativeQuery is not just a replacement of createSQLQuery? The query is executed faster?